# jQuery event.target and is(":checked") not working

Tags: jquery

Just a simple question.

I'm using

```
console.log(jQuery(event.target).is(":checked"));
```

and it returns false everytime.

If I do a `console.log(jQuery(event.target))` is prints out the input box, so I know event.target is correct.

I can't use `this` here because the jQuery event is bound to a parent div.

Any ideas why this wouldn't work?  Seems easy enough.

EDIT#########################################
Rest of code:

```
jQuery(".core-create-install-pkg-parent").live("click", function(event){
var cls = jQuery(event.target).attr("type");
if(cls != "checkbox"){
    event.stopPropagation();
    jQuery(".core-create-install-pkg-child:first", this).toggle();
}else{
    console.log(event.target);
    if(jQuery(event.target).is(":checked")){
        console.log("it's checked");
        jQuery("input[type=checkbox]", this).removeAttr('checked'); 
    }else{
        console.log("not checked");
        jQuery("input[type=checkbox]", this).attr("checked", true);
    }
}
});
```

And the html looks like:

```
<div class="core-create-install-pkg-parent">
  <div class="core-create-install-pkg-title">
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked>
    plugins
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and yes, the checkbox is checked ;)

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood you, it seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/68Msz/6/

Comment: This will work for me to return if checkbox is checked. Can you provide rest of the code. I doubt that event.target is "pointing" to checkbox.

Comment: @James and Waltsu This is what I expect.  I thought it should work, but it doesn't work on this.  I've double checked to make sure that event.target is the checkbox, I'll keep looking.

Comment: @James http://jsfiddle.net/68Msz/8/  The code I'm using isn't working.  Am I blind?

Comment: See Felix Kling answer below :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with this code snipped is that you instantly revert the control after it toggles.

```
if (jQuery(event.target).is(":checked")) { //Enters if the checkbox is checked
    console.log("it's checked");
    jQuery("input[type=checkbox]", this).removeAttr('checked'); //Removes the checked attribute, effectively unchecking it
} else { //Enters if the checkbox is Unchecked
    console.log("not checked");
    jQuery("input[type=checkbox]", this).attr("checked", true); //Sets the checked attribute, checkbox becomes checked again
}
```

Also i would recommend the prop method of jquery for testing the checked state (which returns true or false). [requires jQuery 1.6)

```
($(event.target).prop("checked")
($(event.target).prop("checked", true)
```

Comment: I beg your pardon?  :)  What do you mean I revert control after it toggled?  After what toggles, the checked state?  It's not like it's being reevaluated, it's inside an if else statement.  So one or the other happens, not "if it's checked, uncheck it and test again"

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you are saying.  Because the checkbox is actually being clicked, the browser is unchecking it, and then it's being tested and I recheck it.  If that's the case, then returning false should solve this problem, but it does not: http://jsfiddle.net/68Msz/11/

Comment: Okay, so what was happening was what Fionn suggested.  The browser was handling the unchecking before I was testing the state (because was using the "click" event instead of say mousedown).  So in my case, I just let the browser do it's thing and check and uncheck children and leave the actual event.target alone.

Comment: I added comments to the code lines, what are you trying to achieve with this code anyway? Currently it works like: o the checkbox just became checked, let's uncheck it again.

Answer (score 21):

No need for jQuery:

```
event.target.checked
```

should work if `event.target` is a checkbox. But then, your code should work as well... if it does not, either the element is not a checkbox or something else is wrong.